# Enabling Freescale IMX6 pull down registers on an input pin

Tags: pulldown, freescale

I'm looking for a way to enable the pull down resistor on a Freescale iMX6 MCU.

I'm running a Linux distribution on it and usually interact with the hardware using a higher-level language, so I'm not 100% familiar with the stuff below.

From what I read in the [i.MX50 Applications Processor Reference Manual](http://cache.freescale.com/files/32bit/doc/ref_manual/IMX50RM.pdf?fpsp=1&WT_TYPE=Reference%20Manuals&WT_VENDOR=FREESCALE&WT_FILE_FORMAT=pdf&WT_ASSET=Documentation), resistor pull up / down options are configured using pad control settings, in particular using the following functions

- PULL_KEEP_CTL (4 bits pull up/down and keeper controls)
- PUS (2 bits pull up/down configuration value)
- PUE (1 bit pull/keep select)
- PKE (1 bit enable/disable pull up, pull down or keeper capability)

I found the pin definition in `arch/arm/plat-mxc/include/mach/iomux-mx6q.h` I found the definition of the pin I'm interested in (it's for this pin where I want to enable the pull down resistor).

```
#define _MX6Q_PAD_DISP0_DAT10__GPIO_4_31    IOMUX_PAD(0x04AC, 0x0198, 5, 0x0000, 0, 0)
```

The IOMUX_PAD definition contains the following

```
#define IOMUX_PAD(_pad_ctrl_ofs, _mux_ctrl_ofs, _mux_mode, _sel_input_ofs, _sel_input, _pad_ctrl)                                  \
```

- _pad_ctrl_ofs - hexadecimal offset of the control register, which selects the electrical circuitry (from page 2336 in IMX35RM.pdf)
- _mux_ctrl_ofs - hexadecimal offset of the MUX control register, which selects the function of the pin
- _mux_mode     - bits 2..0 in MUX control register
- _select_input_ofs - SELECT_INPUT register offset (see table 4-11 IOMUX_CTL Register Addresses from 0x07A8, IMX35RM.pdf)
- _select_input - see table 4-12 Daisy Chain List, IMX35RM.pdf
- _pad_ctrl     - bits to be set in register _pad_ctrl_ofs for configuration selection

I'm wondering if changing the `_pad_ctrl` value would do the trick. 
Would changing the definition of the pin, rebuilding the kernel and restarting the module with the new kernel enable the pull down resistor ?

```
#define _MX6Q_PAD_DISP0_DAT10__GPIO_4_31    IOMUX_PAD(0x04AC, 0x0198, 5, 0x0000, 0, (PAD_CTL_PUS_100K_DOWN | PAD_CTL_PUE | PAD_CTL_PKE))
```

Are there other ways to change the pad control values without rebuilding a kernel and restarting the module ?

Answer (score 1):

Check if you can access /dev/mem which gives you access to your entire ram and use [mmap](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) to access the [memory-mapped I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) registers you need. I did this on a Beaglebone Black. Here is an [example](https://graycat.io/tutorials/beaglebone-io-using-python-mmap/) of accessing low-level register on a Beaglebone Black, maybe this can give you a hint.
Hope it helps!